# How to access properties T of closed generic class

Tags: generics, properties, c#-3.0

Given an open generic class definition of:

```
public abstract class BaseUI<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged, IChangeTracking, IDataErrorInfo, ISelectable
    where T: new()
{
    public BaseUI()
    {
    }
    public BaseUI(T data)
    {
        // initialization
    }
}
```

and a closed implementation of:

```
public class AccountUI : BaseUI<Account>
{
    public AccountIU()
       : base()
    {

    }
    public AccountUI(Account data)
    : base(data)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I access the properties of T/Account?  Is this possible in 3.5 (i.e. w/o dynamic)

Comment: *Where* do you need to access the properties, and are they included as part of any of the constrained interfaces?

Comment: (FYI, You have a typo in your first constructor.)

Comment: I need to access them in multiple instances, some internal to the class but mostly in the UI or similar consumer

Answer (score 0):

You can access these properties in the derived class through any accessible member of the base class whose type is `T` (or, of course, through any member of the derived class whose type is `Account`).

(There's no point in a public constructor on an abstract type, so I have changed these to protected.)

For example, assuming that the `Account` type has a boolean `IsOverdue` property:

```
public abstract class BaseUI<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged, IChangeTracking, IDataErrorInfo, ISelectable 
    where T: new() 
{ 
    protected BaseUI() {} 
    protected BaseUI(T data) { this.Data = data; } 

    protected T Data { get; private set; }
} 

public class AccountUI : BaseUI<Account>   
{   
    public AccountUI() : base() {}
    public AccountUI(Account data) : base(data) {}

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (this.Data.IsOverdue)
        {
            //... handle overdue account
        }
    }
}
```

Now, there may be a case where you have a reference to `BaseUI<T>` in a generic context, so you don't know what the type argument is at compile time.  In that case, you would need an abstract method in the base class:

```
public abstract class BaseUI<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged, IChangeTracking, IDataErrorInfo, ISelectable 
    where T: new() 
{ 
    protected BaseUI() {} 
    protected BaseUI(T data) { this.Data = data; } 

    protected T Data { get; private set; }

    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}
```

In this example, you would need to add the `override` keyword to the declaration of AccountUI.SomeMethod:

```
public class AccountUI : BaseUI<Account>   
{   
    public AccountUI() : base() {}
    public AccountUI(Account data) : base(data) {}

    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (this.Data.IsOverdue)
        {
            //... handle overdue account
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call `SomeMethod` on any reference to a `BaseUI<T>`.   The derived class is responsible for providing the implementation.  As with the first example, the derived class knows the type argument supplied for `T`, and it can therefore use accessible members of that type.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Perhaps I should elaborate on my original thought.  I was hoping to be able to do something like Account.Property where Property is a property on T.  In other words, to do away with the Data field and go direct to the properties of the generic type.  Otherwise I have to re-create all of the properties which is one of the things I'm trying to avoid by using T

Comment: @JohnWollner I think you could do that in C# 4 and greater, using `dynamic` type, by implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` on your BaseUI class.  That's probably far more trouble than it's worth, however.  You might also run into ambiguity, if your BaseUI class had, for example, an `Update()` method, and so did the underlying business object.  Another approach, which also works in earlier C# versions, would be to emit IL dynamically at runtime, or generate C# at design time, probably using partial classes.